# How do I resolve this: Error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm a newbie to the MEAN stack and am unclear on how to resolve an error in my AngularJS code. This is the error I keep getting:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataFilterProvider <- dataFilter
```

I'm not quite sure where to try to resolve the error. Perhaps my controller file:

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Authentication, Articles) {

         // various $scope methods

    }
]);
```

Anyone have some ideas of things to look into in order to resolve this error?

**UPDATE:**
I tracked it down to this line of one of my view.html files:

```
<em data-ng-bind="article.created | data:'mediumDate'"></em>
```

Perhaps I need to go through my model and make sure I have those values represented properly.

Comment: It generally means somewhere you are trying to inject `dataFilter` into something, but that `dataFilter` is not a valid injectable thing. Can you show the code where you are trying to inject `dataFilter`, and if you believe it is defined, what the code is that does so?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I had a small typo in this line:

```
<em data-ng-bind="article.created | data:'mediumDate'"></em>
```

I needed to change it to:

```
<em data-ng-bind="article.created | date:'mediumDate'"></em> // CHANGED 'data' to 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

try to pass all the dependencies in module like

```
angular.module('articles', ['Authentication', 'Articles']).controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Authentication, Articles) {

         // various $scope methods

    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can search `dataFilter` in your code and post the usage in question. I guess you may be using angularjs filter in your html? eg `<div>{{user | dataFilter }}</div>` And you didn't define it or it is not in the `articles` module.